# Elasticsearch term aggregation and range with timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, range, aggregation

I'm trying to count # of logs grouped by user agent.

This is what I have.

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 30,
  "stored_fields": ["req.headers.user-agent.keyword"],
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_userAgent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "req.headers.user-agent.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to add "Query last 15 mins" feature. I've tried to add 'range' query and I ended up the following query, which does not work.

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 30,
  "stored_fields": ["req.headers.user-agent.keyword"],


  "aggs": {

    "group_by_userAgent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "req.headers.user-agent.keyword"
      },
      "range": {
        "timestamp": {
          "gt": "now-15m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I query terms aggregation with range with "now-x15min" syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `range` should go inside the query section, not aggs. The time range is good as it is

I think what you're looking for is this, the number of docs in the first 30 user-agent buckets, i.e. the top 30 user agents producing the most logs

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gt": "now-15m"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_userAgent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "req.headers.user-agent.keyword",
        "size": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I get 0 result when I add "query" (Copied and pasted your code". Removing "query" returns data correctly.

Comment: Is your `timestamp` field a `date` field? What do you get when running `GET myindex`?

Comment: Yes, it is "Type: date", but it is named @timestamp.

Comment: if you remove the query and add `"size": 1, "sort": {"timestamp": "desc"}` what is the timestamp of the first document?

Comment: It says "No mapping found for [timestamp]" so I tried "sort": {"@timestamp": "desc"} instead. This is output 

@timestamp: "2019-03-14T23:59:59.959Z"

Comment: Ok then you need to use `@timestamp` in the range query as well, not `timestamp`, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You are correct. I just tried @timestamp and it worked, but not with "now-15m" syntax. It worked with "2019-03-14T21:59:00" format.

Comment: Actually, it worked with now-15m. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in two ways to achieve aggregation results for user-agent.

```
POST phrase_index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "date_range_filtered_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-15m/m"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_userAgent": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "req.headers.user-agent.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 30,
  "stored_fields": ["req.headers.user-agent.keyword"]
}


POST phrase_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-15m/m"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_userAgent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "req.headers.user-agent.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 30,
  "stored_fields": ["req.headers.user-agent.keyword"]
}
```

Comment: The problem with the first is that the aggregation will run on ALL documents, not only on the ones from the last 15 minutes. hence why the range is needed inside the query section and not only in the aggregation section. The second option is basically like what I suggested. The OP will tell but he probably doesn't need any hits since he wants the count of logs grouped by user agents, so returning hits doesn't make any sense here, I think he meant the first 30 user agent buckets in the terms aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

You need a filter aggregation first to apply the range query, then add a terms sub-aggregation.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: The time filter can go inside the query section

Comment: @Val, I'm not sure but maybe the poster just want to filter in the aggregation without changing the hits list

Comment: According to the OP, he wants to count the number of logs grouped by user agent. Sounds like a simple terms aggregation to me. No need for hits as they won't be grouped anyway.

Comment: @Val, what makes me confused is his original code contains `"size": 30`

Comment: Yes, but by putting the range query where he put it, that also means he's just starting with ES :-)

Comment: Thank you both and yes, I'm just starting ES :)